# wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, p7zip

*OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit.*

I would like to compile the following:

> ```
> p7zip_16.02_src_all.tar.bz2
> ```

with SHA256:

> ```
> 5eb20ac0e2944f6cb9c2d51dd6c4518941c185347d4089ea89087ffdd6e2341f
> ```

I extracted it as follows:

```
tar -xjf p7zip_16.02_src_all.tar.bz2
```

I read README file, specifically, that I need to replace the makefile with my machine's equivalent:

> ```
> According to your OS, copy makefile.linux,
> makefile.freebsd, makefile.cygwin, ...
>     over makefile.machine
> ```

So I did:

```
cp makefile.linux_amd64 makefile.machine
```

It also says it is possible to build in parallel, in my case of 8 cores:

> ```
> If you want to make a parallel build on a 4 cpu machine : make -j 4 TARGET
> ```

So I did:

```
make -j 8 all_test
```

With the result:

> ```
> Everything is Ok
> ```

Now, I would like to proceed further, but:

```
make -j 8 depend
```

this **throws errors**:

> ```
> fatal error: wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory
> ```

So, I searched for a package that contains the header file:

```
apt-file search wxprec.h
```

which says:

> ```
> wx3.0-headers: /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/wxprec.h
> ```

So, I installed that package:

```
sudo apt-get install wx3.0-headers
```

but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Could this help http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=19402.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the dependencies before `make` command :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep p7zip
```

It will install the missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev
```

did the trick.